# Set an interface to nil in Golang

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, interface

I'm trying to set an internal value of an interface to `nil` something like the following :

```
typ := &TYP{InternalState: "filled"}
setNil(typ)

fmt.Printf("Expecting that %v to be nil", typ)
```

And I need to know how to implement the `setNil(typ interface{})` method.

For more details [see this code in play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/W-0yw1NrD9).

Comment: But why? Can you not use a boolean.

Comment: @yene: I like to keep my interface design cleaner.

Comment: I don't see how it could be done without returning `nil` directly from the function. Just think about `setNil(3)` for instance.

Answer (score 8):

The thing is you don't have an interface value. You have a pointer value, a pointer to a concrete type. That is not the same as an interface value.

If you want to change the value of a variable of any type, you have to pass a pointer to it. This also includes variables of interface type, and also variables of pointer type. This is one of those very rare cases when a pointer to `interface{}` makes sense (`*interface{}`), in fact it's inevitable.

But if your function expects an interface and you pass a non-interface value, an interface value will be created implicitly and you could only `nil` this implicitly created value.

So we have 2 different / distinct cases:

#### Function to `nil` an `interface{}`

```
func setNilIf(v *interface{}) {
    *v = nil
}
```

Using it:

```
var i interface{} = "Bob"
fmt.Printf("Before: %v\n", i)
setNilIf(&i)
fmt.Printf("After: %v\n", i)
```

Output:

```
Before: Bob
After: <nil>
```

So it works.

#### Function to `nil` a pointer; using `unsafe`

Actually this is your case. We want to change the value of a variable of pointer type. To accept a pointer to any type, we can use [`unsafe.Pointer`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer). `unsafe.Pointer` is a [language support](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_unsafe), it's a special pointer type which can be converted from and to any pointer type.

We want to accept the address (pointer) of the pointer variable, which is something like `**SomeType`. To actually be able to assign a new value (`nil`) to the pointer variable, we have to dereference it (`*` operator). But `unsafe.Pointer` cannot be dereferenced, so first we have to convert it to a pointer to pointer to "something", but since we only want to assign `nil` (which is the same to all pointer types regardless of the type of the pointed value), the "something" doesn't matter, I will just use `int`, and so I will convert the `unsafe.Pointer` pointer value to `**int`.

```
func setNilPtr(p unsafe.Pointer) {
    *(**int)(p) = nil
}
```

Using it:

```
typ := &TYP{InternalState: "filled"}
fmt.Printf("Before: %v\n", typ)
setNilPtr(unsafe.Pointer(&typ))
fmt.Printf("After: %v\n", typ)
```

Output:

```
Before: &{filled}
After: <nil>
```

So this one also works. There is still another way using reflection:

#### Function to `nil` a pointer; using `reflect`

You can also `nil` a pointer using reflection only ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package). We still have to pass the address of the variable of pointer type. Note that in this case the type of the parameter will simply be `interface{}`. And it will contain a dynamic type like `**SomeType`. Since pointers have zero value `nil`, we can obtain such a value with [`reflect.Zero()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Zero) which we will set using [`Value.Set()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Set):

```
func setNilPtr2(i interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    v.Elem().Set(reflect.Zero(v.Elem().Type()))
}
```

Using it:

```
typ2 := &TYP{InternalState: "filled"}
fmt.Printf("Before: %v\n", typ2)
setNilPtr2(&typ2)
fmt.Printf("After: %v\n", typ2)
```

Output:

```
Before: &{filled}
After: <nil>
```

So this one also works. Try these on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/20soSdSoQR).

---

But seriously: if you want to `nil` something, assign `nil` to it. Do not complicate things unnecessarily.

```
i = nil
typ = nil
```

Comment: Thanks icza , but I want avoid my client to know about `unsafe.Pointer` , and I don't want my client pass the type as `*interface{}`. so could you make this work ?=> http://play.golang.org/p/KhR4-BHMPW

Comment: @Mohsen See edited answer. I added a 3rd way, using only reflection  inside the function. You have to pass the address of the variable, you can't avoid that, but this one does not use `unsafe.Pointer`.

Comment: :Thx very much icza, but I have to , take a look : http://play.golang.org/p/aPslX_vgiJ (why doesn't go have generic!) :-)