# Replace value of interface

Tags: pointers, go

I want to replace an interface's value like this:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Fooer interface {Foo(string)}

type Foo struct {foo string}

func (f *Foo) Foo(bar string) {f.foo = bar}

var z = &Foo{foo : "new"}

func swap(fooer Fooer) {fooer = z}

func main() {
    f :=  &Foo{foo: "old"}
    fmt.Printf("%s (want &{old})\n", f)
    swap(f)
    fmt.Printf("%s (want &{new})", f)
}
```

But i get:

```
&{old}
&{old}
```

I tried around with various calls (`fooer *= z`, `*fooer = *z`, ..) but I cant seem to get it right.

You can try this example at play.golang: http://play.golang.org/p/EZEh3X8yHC

---

Okay, I think it works like this:

```
func swap(fooer Fooer) {
    foo, _ := fooer.(*Foo)
    *foo = *z
}
```

Comment: Your edit is probably more like what you intended, but then there's no point to the interface, since you can only assign the exact same type.

Comment: yup absolutely right :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set an interface to nil in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841630/set-an-interface-to-nil-in-golang)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like most things in Go, interfaces are simply values. Assigning a new value within a function isn't going to change the value copied into the function arguments.

Because you want to replace the interface value, you need a pointer to the value just like you would any other. It's a very rare case where you could use a pointer to an interface: http://play.golang.org/p/EZEh3X8yHC

```
func swap(fooer *Fooer) {
    z := Fooer(&Foo{foo: "new"})
    *fooer = z
}

func main() {
    var f Fooer = &Foo{foo: "old"}
    fmt.Printf("%s (want &{old})\n", f)
    swap(&f)
    fmt.Printf("%s (want &{new})", f)
}
```

But, since a pointer to an interface is almost always a mistake (you can see we have to be very explicit to make this work), you should *really* have a good reason for implementing something this way, and document it well.

What you most likely want is to extract the pointer from the interface, and assign a new value in there (which is what you added to end of your question). This is a much better construct, but the type must match, so the interface isn't needed.

Comment: ok one more question then, how does it work that `json.Encode(interface{})` or `gob.Encode(interface{})` use interfaces as args but are still able to write the values somehow

Comment: @machete: Those use reflection and type assertions, and you have to pass in a pointer to be assigned. You still can't change the dynamic type of the interface, i.e. if you pass in a `*string`, you can't replace it with an `*int`. A similar function via reflection: http://play.golang.org/p/u_lBBPeRfz

Answer (score -1):

I think this is better. You assign the "new" string to replace the "old" in Foo instance.

```
...

func swap(fooer Fooer) {
    fooer.Foo(z.foo)
}

func main() {
    f := Foo{foo: "old"}
    fmt.Printf("%s (want &{old})", f)
    fmt.Println("")

    swap(&f)
    fmt.Printf("%s (want &{new})", f)

}
```